# Falcon for building API

Tags: api, postman, falconframework, falcon

How do I obtain the req in falcon as json and not string as seperate key value pairs.

If {"a:213","b":32435} 
How do i make sure a is passed and then obtain value of a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following code will help you:

```
json_data = json.loads(req.stream.read())
```

OR if you want to specify specific encoding format of input data.

```
json_data = json.loads(req.stream.read().decode('utf8'))
```

Please let me know you need further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I hope following code will help you.

```
json_data = json.loads(req.stream.read())
try:
    value_a = json_data['a']
except KeyError as k:
    print 'a is not passed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you asked, but you can transform you raw request (req) to json by using:

```
if req.content_length:
   doc = json.load(req.stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
stream = req.bounded_stream.read()
```

or

```
stream = req.stream.read()
```

I created a BodyParser class as a middleware:

```
class BodyParser(object):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = ctx
    def process_request(self, req, resp):
        if req.method.upper() in ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH']:
            stream = req.stream.read()
            if not stream:
                req.context['body'] = None
                return
            req.context['body'] = json.loads(stream)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

after you translate the req/resp into JSON with:

json.load(req.stream)

you can look at the output as a regular dictionary.